# How should I go upon solving this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question goes like: Describe a basis for the vector subspace of polynomials of $degree$ at most $4$  having
$3$  and $-2$  as its roots.

So, what I've done until now is, I took a vector space $P_4$ consisting of all polynomials of degree 4 or less.
Now I formed a basis $S$ of this as:

$S={\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4}\}$

Now how do I describe the basis for $P_4$ having $3$ and $-2$ as its roots? I don't have any idea what to do after this.

Comment: Can you find one polynomial inside your subspace? Can you characterize all?

Comment: The title of the question should have something to do with the specific question itself. Imagine what would happen if everyone who wanted help for solving a problem would use the title “How should I go upon solving this problem?”.

Comment: I actually didn't know how to title my question properly, that's my bad, I'll try to put a proper title from next time. @JoséCarlosSantos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the polynomial has $3$ and $-2$ as it's roots....so $(x-3)(x+2)$ must divide the polynomial.

Which means any such polynomial in $P_{4}$ should be of the form

$(x-3)(x+2)(ax^{2}+bx+c)=ax^{4}+(b-a)x^{3}+(c-b+6a)x^{2}+(-c-6b)x-6c$

Where $a,b,c$ are members of the underlying field.

So the above expression can be written as $$a(x^{4}-x^{3}-6x^{2})+b(x^{3}-x^{2}-6x)+c(x^{2}-x-6)$$.

So the polynomials $\left\{(x^{4}-x^{3}-6x^{2}),(x^{3}-x^{2}-6x),(x^{2}-x-6)\right\}$ Form a basis for the subspace.

Comment: You blew my cover!

Answer (score 3):

The polynomial must have $(x-3)(x+2)$ as a factor, so it will have the form $(x-3)(x+2)Q(x)$ where $Q(x)$ is another polynomial. To get the product with degree at most $4$, $Q(x)$ must then have degree at most $2$. Therefore ... oops, phone is ringing. Can you finish?

Comment: $(x-3)(x+2)Q(x)$ is what I was looking for. The answer by Arghyadeep Chatterjee even completed the problem, so I didn't have to think much. Thank you for this.
@Oscar Lanzi

Comment: Actually I wanted you to think it through. Then you learn. (The "phone call" was a ruse.)

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, but before I could go on thinking myself, it was already answered. Thank you for the concern though :)

Answer (score 3):

Following your initial idea (which might not turn out to be the easiest), you could ask what condition a general polynomial $P=c_0+c_1X+c_2X^2+c_3X^3+c_4X^4$ should satisfy such that both $P[X:=3]=0$ and $P[X:=-2]=0$ (i.e., both $3$ and $-2$ are roots of $P$). The second part gives the condition $c_1-2c_1+4c_2-8c_3+16c_4=0$, and the first part is similar. These are linear (homogeneous) equations in $5$ unknown, for which the general solution describes the subspace you are looking for.

Now solving the system describes the solution in terms of free parameters (typically three of the unknowns can be chosen freely, so they will be parameters, and the remaining ones are then determined by the equations). Making one of the free parameters nonzero and the others zero will give you a particular solution; three distinct particular solutions can so be found (one for each choice of the free parameter to make nonzero). The solutions so found will be a basis for the subspace of solutions (this is a general property of linear homogeneous systems, if the set of parameters is correctly found, and therefore both compete and independent).

Comment: Thank you for explaining, I tried to solve by this way and it certainly is not the easiest and will also consume more time compared to other ways described in the answers by Arghyadeep Chatterjee and Oscar Lanzi. But I will still remember this approach just in case. @Marc van Leeuwen